# how can I load a file contained on a variable? Python

Tags: python

I have a text file (mainfile.txt) that contains the name of other 3 text files, named `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, & `file3.txt`.

I am trying to load the 3 files contained in the main file with a loop but I do not know how to do it.

All the files are contained in the same folder.

this is what I am trying to do:
my main file is 'satriano.txt.with a loop for I want to load the 3 files contained in 'satriano.txt' called Pr1, 2 and 3.

```
file_name=np.loadtxt('satriano.txt', 'str')
n=len(file_name)
for w in range (0,n)
    np.loadtxt('file_name[w]',file_name)
```

this is wrong for Python obviously as I am trying matlab sintaxes, sorry

Comment: the 3 files I want to load have numerical data on them. I want to open the content of each file and work it out

Comment: Loading files given a file path is easy with the `open` function. However to get a useful answer, please add to your question the file content of your paths file, as well as one of the numerical data files (different formats are handled differently).

Comment: Please improve your question by adding relevant code.

Comment: how can I post the code with python format and no simple text?

Comment: @OmarVelazquez Add 4 spaces at the beginning of each code line

Comment: @petey code added, thanks!

Comment: @TLousky code added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Missing ':' at the end of for. You can directly use `w` as your filename if you don't use `range`.

```
import numpy as np
file_name=np.loadtxt('satriano.txt', 'str')
n=len(file_name)
for w in file_name:
    np.loadtxt(w)
```

Comment: one last question, I am using the jupyter notebook and at the end of the script I get 3 figures I want to plot just in one figure. what is the similar function on Python than matlab's 'hold on, hold all'?

Comment: `%matplotlib inline`
`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`
`plt.plot(firststuff, 'b');`
`plt.plot(secondstuff, 'g');`
It will plot everything on the same figure.